# Variance of an unbiased estimator

Tags: statistics

T1 and T2 are unbiased estimators of theta. 
T3=aT1+(1-a)T2 and is also an unbiased estimator of theta.

If T1 and T2 are independent, determine the best choice of a so that Var(T3) is this smallest.

I know I have to differentiate the variance of T3 and make it equal to 0, but I am struggling to find the variances of T1 and T2.

I have:
Var(T3)=a^2*T1 + (1-a)^2 *T2
but I can't figure out how to get any further? I have tried to consider covariance but it doesn't help.

Comment: Presumably you meant to say $Var(T_3)=a^2\, Var(T_1) + (1-a)^2 \, Var(T_2)$.  For what you have told us, the best you can do is differentiate this with respect to $a$ and solve to give a value for $a$ in terms of $Var(T_1) $ and $Var(T_2)$

Answer (score 2):

Denoting the variance as $\sigma^2$ and the expectation with an overline,

$$\sigma^2_{T_3}=\overline{(a(T_1-T)+(1-a)(T_2-T))^2}\\
=\overline{a^2(T_1-T)^2+2a(1-a)(T_1-T)(T_2-T)+(1-a)^2(T_2-T)}\\
=a^2\overline{(T_1-T)^2}+(1-a)^2\overline{(T_2-T)^2}\\
=a^2\sigma^2_{T_1}+(1-a)^2\sigma^2_{T_2}.$$

This is a quadratic polynomial in $a$,

$$(\sigma^2_{T_1}+\sigma^2_{T_2})a^2-2\sigma^2_{T_2}a+\sigma^2_{T_2}$$ which achieves its maximum at 
$$a=\frac{\sigma^2_{T_2}}{\sigma^2_{T_1}+\sigma^2_{T_2}}.$$

and the minimum variance is
$$\frac{\sigma^2_{T_1}\sigma^2_{T_2}}{\sigma^2_{T_1}+\sigma^2_{T_2}}.$$

In particular, when $\sigma^2_{T_1}=\sigma^2_{T_2}$ we get $a=\frac12$ and $\sigma^2_{T_3}=\frac12\sigma^2_{T_1}$.